# How to reference values in one data frame according to those in another data frame?

Tags: r, pattern-matching, dataframe

I am new to R and am puzzled by this problem when manipulating some environmental monitoring data.

I have two datasets recording the actual monitoring time-series and the monitoring site information, respectively. I stored them in two data frames `monitoring` and `sites`:

`monitoring:`

```
                  date       site obs
 1 2001-01-01 10:00:00  riverside  NA
 2 2001-01-01 11:00:00  riverside  52
 3 2001-01-01 12:00:00  riverside  52
 4 2001-01-01 13:00:00  riverside  56
 5 2001-01-01 10:00:00       dorm  52
 6 2001-01-01 11:00:00       dorm  64
 7 2001-01-01 12:00:00       dorm  76
 8 2001-01-01 13:00:00       dorm  80
 9 2001-01-01 10:00:00        kfc  78
10 2001-01-01 11:00:00        kfc  74
11 2001-01-01 12:00:00        kfc  66
12 2001-01-01 13:00:00        kfc  68
```

`sites:`

```
        site       type
 1      DORM   suburban
 2       KFC      urban
 3 RIVERSIDE      rural
```

I want to add a `site.type` column in `monitoring` with information extracted from `sites` as shown below:

```
                  date       site obs site.type
 1 2001-01-01 10:00:00  riverside  NA     rural
 2 2001-01-01 11:00:00  riverside  52     rural
 3 2001-01-01 12:00:00  riverside  52     rural
 4 2001-01-01 13:00:00  riverside  56     rural
 5 2001-01-01 10:00:00       dorm  52  suburban
 6 2001-01-01 11:00:00       dorm  64  suburban
 7 2001-01-01 12:00:00       dorm  76  suburban
 8 2001-01-01 13:00:00       dorm  80  suburban
 9 2001-01-01 10:00:00        kfc  78     urban
10 2001-01-01 11:00:00        kfc  74     urban
11 2001-01-01 12:00:00        kfc  66     urban
12 2001-01-01 13:00:00        kfc  68     urban
```

I tried `grep()` in the following command:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(monitoring)) {
  monitoring$site.type[i] <- as.character(sites$type[grep(monitoring$site[i], sites$site, ignore.case = T)])
}
```

It worked OK on this small example set of `monitoring`. However, when I applied it to my real dataset with 654,525 records, it never stopped running on my i5-2400 computer with 16 GB RAM...

I tried to search for existing questions on stackoverflow and did find some answers offering the same solution to similar scenarios, so was even more confused why it did not work in my case. Therefore,

1. Could someone kindly point out where the problem is?
2. May I ask how to avoid `for` looping in this case, as it may
   not be as "fashionable" and efficient? :)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `?merge` should work much better ...

Comment: Do those 2 `data.frame`s have the same dimensions?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for pointing me to the right direction - is there any one-step solution to `merge` the two if the matching columns are with differently capitalised contents (see my comment below @January 's sollution)?

Comment: @aL3xa No, `monitoring` is 654,525 by 8, and `sites` is 75 by 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper way to do it is to use `merge`, as Ben suggested, but here is a simple trick:

```
rownames( sites ) <- tolower( sites$site )
```

Now you can get access `sites` using keys such as `riverside`, for example try `sites[ "riverside", ]`. The `tolower()` function is used only to turn `RIVERSIDE` into `riverside`. Therefore, you can do

```
monitoring$site.type <- sites[ monitoring$site, "type" ]
```

Comment: How clever! Thanks very much for the great idea - having read @Ben 's suggestion and was trying to `match` the case in both `site` columns (site names in `site` in the real `monitoring` often have more than one word and are initial capitalised for each word, such as `Williamson Park`, and I'd like to keep this format for output). With your solution I kept the upper case in `sites$site` and used `toupper(monitoring$site)` for indexing and it worked perfectly in a second! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `merge` as suggested by Ben would be easy

```
monitoring
sites$site <- factor(tolower(sites$site)) # cols are unordered

merge(monitoring, sites, by='site')

# fixing col order...
merge(monitoring, sites, by='site')[,c('date', 'site', 'obs', 'type')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @jilber. I also think it'll be easy to `merge` the two if contents in both `site` columns are of the same capitalisation. However, in the real `monitoring$site` each initial letter is capitalised, e.g., `Stratford-upon-Avon Centre`, while in the real `sites$site` all is capitalised as shown in the example, and I'd like the output in the first format. Just for a test, I converted both columns to small letters only, and used `merge` by `site`. In the resulting data frame, the time-series are no longer in order. Any idea why? Many thanks again.